# PDO bind value for MATCH AGAINST FULL TEXT search

Tags: php, pdo

```
$query=SELECT * FROM DB WHERE MATCH (email, name, live) 
AGAINST (:search IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT :start, 20";
//:start is row count from previous query

$SQL=$db->prepare($query);                          
$SQL->bindValue(':search', '+'.$search.'*', PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Hi, im new in PHP PDO and I have a full text search query use PDO

Is this correct to bind value like this, I put **+** and ***** inside of `bindValue();`

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM DB WHERE MATCH (email, name, live) 
AGAINST ('+searchword1 +searchword2*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Will become something like:

```
SELECT * FROM DB WHERE MATCH (email, name, live) 
AGAINST (:search IN BOOLEAN MODE)

$value = '+searchword1 +searchword2*';

$SQL = $db->prepare($query);                          
$SQL->bindValue(':search', $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```